# Why won't my HTML button run my Python script?

Tags: python, html, button, cgi

So, I tried to create a **button** for my web page. The function of the button is to run my Python script from the **Raspberry Pi**. I tried to do this by following the **CgiScript** guide. But the moment I click on the button it only shows me the script on the web page, instead of running it from Thonny IDLE on the Pi.
Here is my **HTML** code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Twisted Twister</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="nl-nl">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1252" >
<style>
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFB0FE
    background url("texture.png")
    }`

#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#arrowPad {
    border: 10px #FFFFFF;
}

#USERDATA {
    background: 10px #FFFFFF;

}

#USERDATA.h {
    background: 10px #FFFFFF;

}

#USERDATA.h:hover {
    background: 10px #FFFFFF;

}
</style>
<body>
<>
<div id="USERDATA"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#USERDATA').load('RequestUserData.php')
        }, 200);
    })
</table>
</script>

<table>
<div id="PI"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#PI').load('RequestPiData.php')
        }, 200);
    });

</script>
</table>

<div id="fixed">
  <table id="arrowPad">
        <tr>
        <td id="USERDATA" class="h"><a href="/usr/lib/cgi- 
bin/aantalSpelers2.py" ><img src="https://imgflip.com/s/meme/Blank-Nut- 
Button.jpg" width="150" height="150" id="a2" alt="PythonScript"></img></a> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my **Python** script
    def main():

```
# 0 changes to 1 when players are joining the game
speler_een = 0
speler_twee = 0
speler_drie = 0
speler_vier = 0

# This function makes an inventory of how many players are involved
class HoeveelSpelers:
    def verkrijg_aantal_spelers(spelers_totaal):
        hoeveelSpelers = int(input('Hoeveel spelers spelen er mee? (1-4) '))

        while (hoeveelSpelers > 4 or hoeveelSpelers < 1):
            print('Dit is niet een geldige hoeveelheid spelers. Probeer het 
opnieuw. ')
            hoeveelSpelers = int(input('Hoeveel spelers spelen er mee? (1-4) 
'))

        return hoeveelSpelers

h = HoeveelSpelers()
spelers_totaal = h.verkrijg_aantal_spelers()

if (spelers_totaal == 4):
    speler_een = 1
    speler_twee = 1
    speler_drie = 1
    speler_vier = 1
elif (spelers_totaal == 3):
    speler_een = 1
    speler_twee = 1
    speler_drie = 1
elif (spelers_totaal == 2):
    speler_een = 1
    speler_twee = 1
elif (spelers_totaal == 1):
    speler_een = 1

print(speler_een, speler_twee, speler_drie, speler_vier)

main()
```

So basically what I want to do is hit the button on the webpage and run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling Python code from HTML is not as easy as creating a hyperlink to the file path (but also not very complicated once you understand the basics).

In order to make your Python code accessible from your HTML page you need to run a proper Python web server in the back (e.g. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)).

Sticking to the Flask example - if you want to have a button, that triggers a certain function (e.g. `foo()`) you would need to register an "endpoint" that maps an URL to that function (example taken from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/)):

#### backend

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def foo():
    pass # define the action here

...
```

Assuming you are running the Flask server on port 5000 on the same host as your frontend the button would need to link to something like

#### frontend

```
...
<a href="http://localhost:5000/">click here</a>
...
```

Without a return value the actual processing is only happening in the backend - without your frontend noticing it. When it comes to returning values (as I assume is the case for your example) things become slightly more challenging. I can only recommend the [Flask Mega Tutorial (by Miguel Grinberg)](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). It covers a lot of the basics as well as rather advanced features - which might help you layout our application.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thank you Joshua, I used the os.popen(Python3  #scripy.py) and that really worked. Instead of typing the whole localhost in the frontend, I wrote the app.route in the href and that worked really fine